# git clone from machine behind firewall TO remote machine

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

I can ssh from my work machine to my home machine

This works

Work$> ssh -x -Y myname@homemachine.dydns.org

Now if I want to clone a git repo on my work machine to my home machine . I issue the command

Work$> git clone ~/my_new_work_git_repo myname@homemachine.dydns.org:/home/myname

But this ends up creating a directory named "myname@homemachine.dydns.org" with subdirectories "home" and then "myname" on mY work machine . The repo gets clones to this silly named directory on my local Work  machine no matter what URL scheme I try ssh:// or rsync://

What am I doing wrong. I read through several of the questions that seemed related but cannot figure out why this fails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell from your question which direction you are trying to clone in.

If your repository is on your home machine, and you are trying to clone it onto your work machine, then you have the argument order backwards. It's `git clone original clone`, so in your case:

```
git clone myname@homemachine.dydns.org:/home/myname ~/my_new_work_git_repo
```

If you mean that you are trying to clone a repository that is at work, so you can have it on you home machine, then you will need to be able to SSH in the other direction; from your home machine, to your work machine. You cannot "push" a clone over SSH, you can only "pull" (that is, you can only create the clone on the local machine, either from a local or remote repo).

If you need to get the repo from your work machine to your home machine, but can't SSH in from your home machine, you can just clone into a new bare repository, and then `scp` it to your home machine. Now when you're at home, you can clone that bare repository, work with it, push to it and so on. When you're at work, you can pull from it, push to it, and so on.

Here's an example of how this would work:

```
Work$> git clone --bare ~/my_work_repo repo.git
Work$> scp -r repo.git myname@homemachine.dydns.org:/home/myname
Work$> git remote add home myname@homemachine.dydns.org:/home/myname/repo.git

Home$> git clone repo.git my_home_repo
Home$> cd my_home_repo
Home$> # edit, commit, etc
Home$> git push origin

Work$> git remote update
Work$> git pull home master
```

Comment: Thanks Brian: "You cannot "push" a clone over SSH, you can only "pull" (that is, you can only create the clone on the local machine, either from a local or remote repo)." Thats the answer I was looking for. I have rsynced my repo and will follow your workflow to stay in sync

Comment: scp -r needed as folder need to be recursicely transferred. (stackoverflow dont allow 1 character edits)

Comment: @flurdy Thanks, yeah, that's what I meant.